How to introduce error to the stim circuit exported from Crumble
I am not successful to add a noise model to the circuit that I created in Crumble and transferred into STIM with stim.Circuit(''' .... '''), without adding them by hand.
I see the examples of stim.Circuit.generated() method, and looking for similar models.

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please share your code? This would help to better answer your question.

Stim doesn't include methods to add noise to arbitrary circuits. You will need to write your own code to do this, or find code that does it.
I usually attach the code I use for making circuits to papers, and this includes code for adding noise to circuits. For example, see the file src/gen/_chunk/_noise.py from 'Data for "Magic state cultivation: growing T states as cheap as CNOT gates"'. It's used like so:
import gen

p = 1e-3
noise = gen.NoiseModel.uniform_depolarizing(p)

circuit: stim.Circuit = ...
noisy_circuit = noise.noisy_circuit(circuit)

